# Android CustomAdapter - Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a Custom ArrayAdapter as per [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429), however I am getting error on this line:

`Drawer drawer_data[] = new Drawer[] {`

that `Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array`

**Drawer.java**

```
public class Drawer {
    public int mIcon;
    public String mText;

    public Drawer() {
        super();
    }

    public Drawer(int mIcon, String mTitle) {
        super();
        this.mIcon = mIcon;
        this.mText = mTitle;
    }
}
```

**DrawerAdapter.java**

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drawer> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Drawer data[] = null;

    public Drawer_CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Drawer[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DrawerHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new DrawerHolder();
            holder.mIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);
            holder.mText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (DrawerHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Drawer drawer = data[position];
        holder.mIcon.setImageResource(drawer.mIcon);
        holder.mText.setText(drawer.mText);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class DrawerHolder {
        ImageView mIcon;
        TextView mText;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
    Drawer drawer_data[] = new Drawer[] { // <<<< ERROR
            for(int i=0; i<mDrawerItems; i++) {
                new Drawer(mDrawerIcons[i],mDrawerItems[i]);
            }
    };

    DrawerAdaper adapter = new DrawerAdapter(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item,drawer_data);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162344/variable-must-provide-either-dimension-expressions-or-an-array-initializer-erro) but I don't know how to modify my code.

**New Error: NullPointerEception stack trace:**

```
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at com.TVGenius.DrawerAdapter.getView(DrawerAdapter.java:42)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-31 14:05:39.604: E/AndroidRuntime(14724):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:** Line 42 is - `holder.mIcon.setImageResource(drawer.mIcon);`

**EDIT 2:**

1. Where do I add these setter and getter methods? Which .java file?
2. Where do I call the `drawer.getIcon()`.

   ```
   public int getIcon() {
       return this.mIcon;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
       return this.mText;
   }
   ```

Comment: try this `Drawer drawer_data[] = new Drawer[mDrawerItems.size()]`

Comment: This solved the error. But when I ran the app. It crashed on RunTime: Error: NullPointer in `Drawer_CustomAdapter.java line 42: holder.mIcon.setImageResource(drawer.mIcon);` any ideas?

Comment: Posted in main post above.

Comment: use a setter and getter in drawer class. and call `drawer.getIcon()`

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm still beginner... :(

Comment: are you sure that `holder.mIcon` is not null ?

Comment: I just tested: `if (holder.mIcon != null) { holder.mIcon.setIm...}; }` result: not `null`

Comment: where do you set your text and icon to your `Drawer` class? show us the code

Comment: They are retrieved inside my Activity onCreate using: `mDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array);` and `mDrawerIcons = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.drawer_icons);`. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Drawer drawer_data[] = new Drawer[mDrawerItems.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < mDrawerItems.size(); i++){
drawer_data[i] = new Drawer(mDrawerIcons[i],mDrawerItems[i]);
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Same error. I think a `setter` and `getter` methods are needed.

Comment: Try logging to find out whether the holder.mIcon is null or drawer.mIcon is null.

Comment: It is for the above answer which you told fixed the issue.

Comment: The code for Drawer class is above in the main post- called "Drawer" in bold.

Comment: Have you set the values for mDrawerIcons? That is mDrawerIcons[i] is not null right?

Comment: Yes. They are set using: `mDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array);` and `mDrawerIcons = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.drawer_icons);`

Comment: Try specifying  the resource id directly in holder.mIcon.setImageResource(drawer.mIcon) .  That is replace drawer.mIcon with R.id.imageName  and see if its crashing. If its not, then try printing all values in drawer.Icons and see if there is any mistake in it.

Comment: Solved. I didn't implement the code properly. Inside the for loop, I had `new Drawer...` instead of `drawer_data[i] = new Drawer...`. My  mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way**

```
Drawer drawer_data[] = new Drawer[mDrawerItems.length]

             for(int i=0; i<mDrawerItems.length; i++) {
                drawer_data[]=new Drawer(mDrawerIcons[i],mDrawerItems[i]);
            }


    DrawerAdaper adapter = new DrawerAdapter(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item,drawer_data);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Tried. Error resolved, but app crashed on RunTime. Error: NullPOinter: see comment on Question above.